# Using recursion tree to find upper bound guess

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

How can I find the complexity of this recursion?

> T(n) = 2 T(n<sup>1/2</sup>) + O(lg n)

Comment: Do you mean T(n)= 2 T(n^(1/2)) + O (lgn) ?

Comment: You might need to use something like the Akra Bazzi thm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra-Bazzi_theorem

Answer (score 2):

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3956416/395857)

T(n) = 2 T(n^(1/2)) + O(lg n)

Let m = log<sub>2</sub> n;

=> T(2<sup>m</sup>) = 2T( 2<sup>m / 2</sup> ) + O(m)

Now renaming K(m) = T(2<sup>m</sup>) => K(m) = 2K(m/2) + O(m)

Then use the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) for K. To conclude, O(T) ~ O(lg K).

Comment: Shouldn't it be "K(m) = 2K(m/2) + O(m)" (not "O(lg m)") in the penultimate line?

Answer (score 1):

There is a classical method to resolve these recurrence relations where the value for the `n`th term depends on the `p`th exponentially\quadratically smaller than `n`(here `p = n^(1/2) = exp(1/2*log(n))`).

Change the variable `n` to `exp(k)` and define a function `F` such that

```
  F(k) = T(exp(k))
```

The first step give you

```
  T(exp(k)) = 2 T(exp(k/2))  + O(k)
```

The second step give you

```
   F(k) = 2F(k/2) + O(k)
```

Which is well know to be (for this proof search yourself) `O(klog(k))`.
Now just `n = exp(k) => k = log(n)` and you finally obtain

```
 T(n) = O(log(n) * log(log(n)))
```

Comment: (Same reply as mine with a different log base. But it's always nice to change the base from time to time :) )

Comment: I did not copy your reply if you want to know... and your conclusion is erroneous

Comment: The point of my previous comment was for the readers to understand the two answers are basically the same. I mainly used another SO answer from another thread, so no worries about "copy" ;) Why is my conclusion erroneous?